# Javascript variable inside java variable in JSP

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, jsp

I have a javascript variable 'option'
And I want to use java variable with javascript variable;
var value="${option}"
Here option should be javascript variable.

I've tried
var value="${"+option+"}"; but this didn't worked.

Comment: Please provide more detail in the form of a complete code example

Comment: If your variable option is in JavaScript, why don't you assign it directly without using JSP? var value = option;

Comment: Also, bear in mind that the JSP is compiled in the server side, and the JavaScript is executed in the browser, so when the page arrives at the browser, JSP tags are not there anymore, they're compiled producing an HTML file that the browser runs.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the quotation marks. Please try:

```
var value='${"+option+"}';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't add comments to a question yet, or I would have. So I had to add my idea as an answer. I unfortunately don't have a JSP environment available at the moment to verify my suggestion myself. But I think I know what the questioner has in mind and just want to say, hey try it out like this. If it really helps, I would be happy about an accepted answer ;-).